# for webserver group -Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement cloudformation stack

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, cloud, webserver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c9MD.png)

Everything (ASG, EC2 instances) does appear to be created correctly in AWS. The issue is with web-server group only. I am using default templates available with cloudformation for wordpress multi-AZ RDS database instance for storage.

I'm using the following CloudFormation template--

```
   {
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template WordPress_Multi_AZ: WordPress is web software you can use to create a beautiful website or blog. This template installs a highly-available, scalable WordPress deployment using a multi-az Amazon RDS database instance for storage. It demonstrates using the AWS CloudFormation bootstrap scripts to deploy WordPress. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon EC2 instance, an Application Load Balancer and an Amazon RDS database instance. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template."

  "Parameters" : {
    "VpcId" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description" : "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
    },

    "Subnets" : {
      "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description" : "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a list of at least two existing subnets associated with at least two different availability zones. They should be residing in the selected Virtual Private Cloud."
    },

    "KeyName": {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },

    "InstanceType" : {
      "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "t2.small",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro", "t2.nano", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "t2.large", "m1.small", "m1.medium", "m1.large", "m1.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "m4.large", "m4.xlarge", "m4.2xlarge", "m4.4xlarge", "m4.10xlarge", "c1.medium", "c1.xlarge", "c3.large", "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "c4.large", "c4.xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "g2.8xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "d2.xlarge", "d2.2xlarge", "d2.4xlarge", "d2.8xlarge", "hi1.4xlarge", "hs1.8xlarge", "cr1.8xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "cg1.4xlarge"]
,
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },

    "SSHLocation": {
      "Description": "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    },

    "DBClass" : {
      "Description" : "Database instance class",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "db.t2.small",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "db.t1.micro", "db.m1.small", "db.m1.medium", "db.m1.large", "db.m1.xlarge", "db.m2.xlarge", "db.m2.2xlarge", "db.m2.4xlarge", "db.m3.medium", "db.m3.large", "db.m3.xlarge", "db.m3.2xlarge", "db.m4.large", "db.m4.xlarge", "db.m4.2xlarge", "db.m4.4xlarge", "db.m4.10xlarge", "db.r3.large", "db.r3.xlarge", "db.r3.2xlarge", "db.r3.4xlarge", "db.r3.8xlarge", "db.m2.xlarge", "db.m2.2xlarge", "db.m2.4xlarge", "db.cr1.8xlarge", "db.t2.micro", "db.t2.small", "db.t2.medium", "db.t2.large"]
,
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must select a valid database instance type."
    },

    "DBName" : {
      "Default": "wordpressdb",
      "Description" : "The WordPress database name",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "1",
      "MaxLength": "64",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
    },

    "DBUser" : {
      "NoEcho": "true",
      "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account username",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "1",
      "MaxLength": "16",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
    },

    "DBPassword" : {
      "NoEcho": "true",
      "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account password",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "8",
      "MaxLength": "41",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z0-9]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must contain only alphanumeric characters."
    },

    "MultiAZDatabase": {
      "Default": "false",
      "Description" : "Create a Multi-AZ MySQL Amazon RDS database instance",
      "Type": "String",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "true", "false" ],
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be either true or false."
    },

    "WebServerCapacity": {
      "Default": "1",
      "Description" : "The initial number of WebServer instances",
      "Type": "Number",
      "MinValue": "1",
      "MaxValue": "5",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be between 1 and 5 EC2 instances."
    },

    "DBAllocatedStorage" : {
      "Default": "5",
      "Description" : "The size of the database (Gb)",
      "Type": "Number",
      "MinValue": "5",
      "MaxValue": "1024",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be between 5 and 1024Gb."
    }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.nano"     : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "g2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  }
    },

    "AWSInstanceType2NATArch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.nano"     : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVMG2"  },
      "g2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  }
    }
,
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
      "af-south-1"       : {"HVM64" : "ami-064cc455f8a1ef504", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-east-1"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-f85b1989", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-northeast-1"   : {"HVM64" : "ami-0b2c2a754d5b4da22", "HVMG2" : "ami-09d0e0e099ecabba2"},
      "ap-northeast-2"   : {"HVM64" : "ami-0493ab99920f410fc", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-northeast-3"   : {"HVM64" : "ami-01344f6f63a4decc1", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-south-1"       : {"HVM64" : "ami-03cfb5e1fb4fac428", "HVMG2" : "ami-0244c1d42815af84a"},
      "ap-southeast-1"   : {"HVM64" : "ami-0ba35dc9caf73d1c7", "HVMG2" : "ami-0e46ce0d6a87dc979"},
      "ap-southeast-2"   : {"HVM64" : "ami-0ae99b503e8694028", "HVMG2" : "ami-0c0ab057a101d8ff2"},
      "ca-central-1"     : {"HVM64" : "ami-0803e21a2ec22f953", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "cn-north-1"       : {"HVM64" : "ami-07a3f215cc90c889c", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "cn-northwest-1"   : {"HVM64" : "ami-0a3b3b10f714a0ff4", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "eu-central-1"     : {"HVM64" : "ami-0474863011a7d1541", "HVMG2" : "ami-0aa1822e3eb913a11"},
      "eu-north-1"       : {"HVM64" : "ami-0de4b8910494dba0f", "HVMG2" : "ami-32d55b4c"},
      "eu-south-1"       : {"HVM64" : "ami-08427144fe9ebdef6", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "eu-west-1"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-015232c01a82b847b", "HVMG2" : "ami-0d5299b1c6112c3c7"},
      "eu-west-2"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-0765d48d7e15beb93", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "eu-west-3"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-0caf07637eda19d9c", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "me-south-1"       : {"HVM64" : "ami-0744743d80915b497", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "sa-east-1"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-0a52e8a6018e92bb0", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "us-east-1"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-032930428bf1abbff", "HVMG2" : "ami-0aeb704d503081ea6"},
      "us-east-2"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-027cab9a7bf0155df", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "us-west-1"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-088c153f74339f34c", "HVMG2" : "ami-0a7fc72dc0e51aa77"},
      "us-west-2"        : {"HVM64" : "ami-01fee56b22f308154", "HVMG2" : "ami-0fe84a5b4563d8f27"}
    }

  },

  "Resources" : {

    "ApplicationLoadBalancer" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
      "Properties" : {
        "Subnets" : { "Ref" : "Subnets"}
      }
    },

    "ALBListener" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener",
      "Properties" : {
        "DefaultActions" : [{
          "Type" : "forward",
          "TargetGroupArn" : { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" }
        }],
        "LoadBalancerArn" : { "Ref" : "ApplicationLoadBalancer" },
        "Port" : "80",
        "Protocol" : "HTTP"
      }
    },

    "ALBTargetGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "HealthCheckPath" : "/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php",  
        "HealthCheckIntervalSeconds" : 10,
        "HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds" : 5,
        "HealthyThresholdCount" : 2,
        "Port" : 80,
        "Protocol" : "HTTP",
        "UnhealthyThresholdCount" : 5,
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "VpcId"},       
        "TargetGroupAttributes" :
          [ { "Key" : "stickiness.enabled", "Value" : "true" },
            { "Key" : "stickiness.type", "Value" : "lb_cookie" },
            { "Key" : "stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds", "Value" : "30" }
        ]
      }
    },
   
    "WebServerSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP access via port 80 locked down to the load balancer + SSH access",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "SourceSecurityGroupId" : {"Fn::Select" : [0, {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["ApplicationLoadBalancer", "SecurityGroups"]}]}},
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}}
        ],
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
      }
    },

    "WebServerGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "Subnets" },
        "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
        "MinSize" : "1",
        "MaxSize" : "5",
        "DesiredCapacity" : { "Ref" : "WebServerCapacity" },
        "TargetGroupARNs" : [ { "Ref" : "ALBTargetGroup" } ]
      },
      "CreationPolicy" : {
        "ResourceSignal" : {
          "Timeout" : "PT15M"
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy": {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate": {
          "MinInstancesInService": "1",
          "MaxBatchSize": "1",
          "PauseTime" : "PT15M",
          "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
        }
      }
    },

    "LaunchConfig": {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Metadata" : {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "configSets" : {
            "wordpress_install" : ["install_cfn", "install_wordpress" ]
          },
          "install_cfn" : {
            "files": {
              "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf": {
                "content": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                  "[main]\n",
                  "stack=", { "Ref": "AWS::StackId" }, "\n",
                  "region=", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                ]]},
                "mode"  : "000400",
                "owner" : "root",
                "group" : "root"
              },
              "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf": {
                "content": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                  "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                  "triggers=post.update\n",
                  "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                  "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                          "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                          "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                          "         --configsets wordpress_install ",
                          "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                ]]},          
                "mode"  : "000400",
                "owner" : "root",
                "group" : "root"
              }
            },
            "services" : {
              "sysvinit" : {
                "cfn-hup" : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true",
                              "files" : ["/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf", "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]}
              }
            }
          },

          "install_wordpress" : {
            "packages" : {
              "yum" : {
                "php73"         : [],
                "php73-mysqlnd" : [],
                "mysql57"       : [],
                "httpd24"         : []
              }
            },
            "sources" : {
              "/var/www/html" : "http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz"
            },
            "files" : {
              "/tmp/create-wp-config" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
                  "#!/bin/bash\n",
                  "cp /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'database_name_here'/'",{ "Ref" : "DBName" }, "'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'username_here'/'",{ "Ref" : "DBUser" }, "'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'password_here'/'",{ "Ref" : "DBPassword" }, "'/g\" wp-config.php\n",
                  "sed -i \"s/'localhost'/'",{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "DBInstance", "Endpoint.Address" ] }, "'/g\" wp-config.php\n"
                ]]},
                "mode" : "000500",
                "owner" : "root",
                "group" : "root"
              }
            },
            "commands" : {
              "01_configure_wordpress" : {
                "command" : "/tmp/create-wp-config",
                "cwd" : "/var/www/html/wordpress"
              }
            },
            "services" : {
              "sysvinit" : {
                "httpd" : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                          { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
        "InstanceType"   : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
        "KeyName"        : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                       "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
                       "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

                       "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                       "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                       "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                       "         --configsets wordpress_install ",
                       "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

                       "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
                       "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                       "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
                       "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
        ]]}}
      }
    },

    "DBEC2SecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription": "Open database for access",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [{
        "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
        "FromPort" : "3306",
        "ToPort" : "3306",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId" : { "Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup" }
        }],
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
      }
    },

    "DBInstance" : {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
        "DBName"            : { "Ref" : "DBName" },
        "Engine"            : "MySQL",
        "MultiAZ"           : { "Ref": "MultiAZDatabase" },
        "MasterUsername"    : { "Ref" : "DBUser" },
        "MasterUserPassword": { "Ref" : "DBPassword" },
        "DBInstanceClass"   : { "Ref" : "DBClass" },
        "AllocatedStorage"  : { "Ref" : "DBAllocatedStorage" },
        "VPCSecurityGroups" : [{ "Fn::GetAtt": [ "DBEC2SecurityGroup", "GroupId" ]}]
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    "WebsiteURL" : {
      "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ApplicationLoadBalancer", "DNSName" ]}, "/wordpress" ]]},
      "Description" : "WordPress Website"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details of the specific issue

Comment: Let me know what other information you need? I have shared the screenshot of the entire events list as well.